# Is there a unique device ID for pi cameras?

Tags: camera

I have multiple pi3s and multiple v2.1cameras. I'm taking pictures with a python script using picamera, I use the pis mac address as an identifier for the pi but I was hoping to be able to get a unique id for the camera so I can keep track of which combinations I'm taking pictures with. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks
Craig

Comment: Can you share the script block for taking picture? Do you use custom calls or the standard python calls mention [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/getting-started-with-picamera/)

Comment: Have you seen this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=75436

Comment: Thanks for the link, my searches with 'serial' in them had only given pi serial numbers or reference to the camera serial interface. There wasn't a solution so I'm guessing it isn't straight forward.

Comment: Yes, standard cam.capture call. I use getnode() from uuid to get the pis mac address. I was hoping there was something as easy to get an identifier for the camera and be able to keep track of which combinations of pi and camera took which pictures.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there's no (accessible) serial number for the camera module. From the linked thread above, there's also currently no method of setting an ID on the camera either (messing around with the camera's I2C interface is pretty low level stuff, way below MMAL which is what both picamera and raspistill/raspivid use).