# How do I get Raspberry Pi Camera Serial Number?

Tags: raspicam, picamera

This is necessary so that we can uniquely identify cameras that get moved between pis.

We found that we could get the camera serial by communicating with it over i2c0, but this required enabling i2c0 in boot/config.txt. From what I've read this is discouraged, and furthermore we've observed that doing this can occasionally cause the python picamera library to hang when instantiating a picamera.PiCamera object.

Is there another method through which we can obtain the camera serial that doesn't involve enabling i2c0?

Comment: Related (but w/o answer) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/56286/19949